# Django - "This Field is Required" error on Password field

Tags: django, forms, authentication, django-users

On my Django website, I'm unable to submit my form. Although I have every field filled out, my password field continues to say "This field is required" even as I have typed something in the password field as well.

I have tried removing the required attribute for the password tag but that has not helped.

Here is my code.:

F

**views.py:** specifically for the function signup, the code never reaches within the `if form.is_valid()` block.

```
def signup(request):

    #If user completes the form (hits the sign up button)
    #Send form data to url /signup-complete/ (see signup.html)
    if request.method == 'POST':

        form = SignUpForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():

            user = User.objects.create(

                username= form.cleaned_data['email'], #Note although there is an email field, we don't use it to prevent redundancy
                first_name = form.cleaned_data['first_name'],
                last_name = form.cleaned_data['last_name'],
                password = form.cleaned_data['password'],

            )

            #Extended attribute, must be added seperately
            user.user_extend.is_student = form.cleaned_data['is_student']
            user.save()

            print('user is now created')

            return HttpResponseRedirect('')

    #Render form
    else:

        form = SignUpForm()

    return render(request, 'mainapp/signup.html', {'form': form})
```

**signup.html**

```
<!-- action="/signup_complete/"-->
    <form action="" method="post">
        <!--Security, Cross Site Request Forgery Protection -->
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.non_field_errors }}

        {% for field in form %}
        <div class="form-group">

            {{ field.errors }}
            <!--or field.name == 'confirm_password'-->
            {% if field.name == 'password' %}
            {{ field.label_tag }}
            <input name="{{ field.name }}" class="form-control" type="password" required>

            {% elif field.name == 'email'%}
            {{ field.label_tag }}
            <input name="{{ field.name }}" class="form-control" type="email" required>

            {% elif field.name == 'is_student'%}
            <div class="float-right">
                <input name="{{ field.name }}" type="checkbox">
                {{ field.label_tag }}

            </div>

            <!--First and last name -->
            {% else %}
            {{ field.label_tag }}
            <input name="{{ field.name }}" class="form-control" type="text" required>
            {% endif %}
        </div>


        {% endfor %}

        <!-- Sign up button -->
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary col-md-12" value="sign_up">Sign Up!</button>

        </form>
```

**models.py**

```
class UserExtend(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_student = models.BooleanField(default=None)
```

**SignUpForm (forms.py)**

```
class SignUpForm(forms.Form):
    first_name = forms.CharField(label='First Name', max_length=50)
    last_name = forms.CharField(label='Last Name', max_length=50)
    email = forms.EmailField()
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput, max_length=50)
    
    is_student = forms.BooleanField(label="Are you a student? (Statistical purposes only)")
```

Comment: Please attach the `SignUpForm` class.

Answer (score 0):

First i suggest you look the request carefully to find what field you pass through it.

you can show form simpler.

```
<form>
{{form.password.errors}}

<input name="password" class="classes">
</form>
```

Comment: I think the `field.errors` in my signup.html takes care of each individual's fields + errors already?

Answer (score 0):

Found my error. The problem is that my boostrap was displaying incorrectly that the password field ha an error when in actuality, the checkbox had an error because it did not have a default value.